# Substituting a part of array using re

Tags: python, list

```
9    7   316 Lake St     Arran Dr    St. Catharines, ON L2N 4H4     Phone:  905-934-5885    112.9   123 130 --- 1/1/18
10   Esso    142 Lakeshore Rd    Geneva St   St. Catharines, ON L2N 2T5 Phone:  905-646-4558    112.7   125.9   131.9   --- 1/1/18
11   Petro-Canada    533 Lake St     Linwell Rd  St. Catharines, ON L2N 4H6 Phone:  (905) 937-7719  112.9   125.9   131.9   124.9   1/1/18
```

I have above data where I need to change (905) to 905- so that all data is in similar format.I have tried to read this content as list and import re.

```
import re
for line in data :
    line = re.sub(r"(905) ", "905-", line)
    print(line)
```

But it is not working.How to replace it ?

Comment: This isn't private info, is it? Seems like publicly available stuff, but just want to make sure. Edit: I made sure at least the address and phone number are public.

Comment: Can you post *code* that puts the data you are using in `data`?

Comment: @wjandrea: "Not any more."

Comment: @ScottHunter Save the data as `sample.txt`, then run `with open('sample.txt') as f: data = f.read().splitlines()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is a simple replacement, then you shouldn't use `re`:

```
line = line.replace("(905) ", "905-")
```

---

If you need to replace *more prefixes than just 905*, only then you need regular expressions:

```
line = re.sub(r"\((\d{3})\) ", r"\1-", line)
```

That would also replace `(204) 342-4532` with `204-342-4532`.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the brackets in RE like this

```
re.sub(r"\(905\) ", "905-", line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the parentheses because they are special characters:

```
for line in data :
    line = re.sub("\(905\) ", "905-", line)
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
9    7   316 Lake St     Arran Dr    St. Catharines, ON L2N 4H4     Phone:  905-934-5885    112.9   123 130 --- 1/1/18
10   Esso    142 Lakeshore Rd    Geneva St   St. Catharines, ON L2N 2T5 Phone:  905-646-4558    112.7   125.9   131.9   --- 1/1/18
11   Petro-Canada    533 Lake St     Linwell Rd  St. Catharines, ON L2N 4H6 Phone:  905-937-7719  112.9   125.9   131.9   124.9   1/1/18
```